How to check if user is currently logged in and redirect him to homescreen or else to login screen in Supabase flutter
I am working on a flutter project implemented supabase_flutter. When the user got registered with email and password I redirect him to home screen. But every time when i hot restart my app. Again I have to reenter user credentials. Can someone help for this issue.
I am trying because i am stuck on an issue in flutter app. I am expecting a good fit solution from this community.

Please share your code you have done so far, so anyone can help on this.

Step 1: Set up GetStorage and GetX in your main.dart file
First, import the necessary packages and initialize GetStorage in the main.dart file. Then, define your main application widget and configure the initial route based on the user's login state.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'controllers/auth_controller.dart';
import 'pages/home_page.dart';
import 'pages/login_page.dart';

void main() async {
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
await GetStorage.init();
Get.lazyPut<AuthController>(() => AuthController());
runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final AuthController authController = Get.find();
  authController.checkTokenValidityAndRefresh();

 final initialRoute = authController.isLoggedIn.isTrue ? '/home':'/login';

return GetMaterialApp(
  title: 'Test',
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.white),
    useMaterial3: true,
  ),
  initialRoute: initialRoute,
  getPages: [
    GetPage(name: '/home', page: () => const HomePage()),
    GetPage(name: '/login', page: () => const LoginPage()),
  ],
);
}
}

Step 2: Implement the AuthController to manage login state
Create an AuthController to manage the login state using GetStorage. This controller will read the stored login state during initialization and provide methods to update the login state.
auth_controller.dart
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

class AuthController extends GetxController {
 final box = GetStorage();
 var isLoggedIn = false.obs;

AuthController() {
 isLoggedIn.value = box.read('isLoggedIn') ?? false;
 if (isLoggedIn.value == true) {
  fetchUserData(); // Perform any additional actions if needed
  }
 }

void setLoggedIn(bool status) {
  isLoggedIn.value = status;
  box.write('isLoggedIn', status);
  print(isLoggedIn.value);
}

void fetchUserData() {
  // Add your logic to fetch user data
}
}

